# Databinding to checkbox in wpf

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I have a WPF window with a few checkboxes. I want to bind these checkboxes to boolean properties in my object, so changes in data will be reflected in view, and changes in view will be reflected in data.
Do I have to derive this object from INotifyPropertyChanged?

Answer (score 3):

As the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) suggestes, you will have to do so. You must provide `properties` and inside those `properties` fire the `PropertyChangedEvent`.
Here is an example from the documentation:

```
public string PhoneNumber
    {
        get
        {
            return this.phoneNumberValue;
        }

        set
        {
            if (value != this.phoneNumberValue)
            {
                this.phoneNumberValue = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
```

You will need to make this fit to your needs, though. Please have a look at MSDN on how to implement the interface properly.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, otherwise when you change values in your object, the checkboxes' bindings won't update properly.